# Single item of ListView isn't getting updated

Tags: java, android, listview

Here, I'm having listView with 2 items for now as shown in the image below

[image]

This is the `SimpleAdapter` used for the `ListView`

```
           ListView listProductSup;
           int listItemPos;
           SimpleAdapter pdtAdapter;            
           pdtAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    ProductProgramActivity.this, pdtDataList,
                    R.layout.product_supp_list, new String[]{"pdtSupName", "strKey", "strServQuan", "strMilkQuan", "strWaterQuan", "strDecocQuan", "strPowderQuan"},
                    new int[]{R.id.txt_list_pdt_supp, R.id.key_set, R.id.serve_quan_set, R.id.milk_quan_set, R.id.wat_quan_set, R.id.decoc_quan_set, R.id.pow_quan_set});
            listProductSup.setAdapter(pdtAdapter);
            listProductSup.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent in = null;
                    listItemPos = position;
                    if (categIn.equals("Machine Installation"))
                        in = new Intent(ProductProgramActivity.this, ProgramSettingActivity.class);
                    else if (categIn.equals("Machine Disconnection"))
                        in = new Intent(ProductProgramActivity.this, MachineDisconActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra("idOfIncident", idOfIncident);
                    in.putExtra("orgId", orgId);
                    in.putExtra("assetId", assetId);
                    in.putExtra("pdtId", pdtIdArr.get(position));
                    in.putExtra("pdtSupId", pdtSupIdArr.get(position));
                    startActivityForResult(in,1);
                }
            });
```

After clicking on the list item it goes to the `next activity`. I'm getting all values from `textFields` in that activity. And from there `onBackPressed`  I'm sending back all the assigned values like here

```
public void backWithData() {
        Intent in = new Intent();
        in.putExtra("pdtSupId", pdtSupId);
        in.putExtra("strKey", strKey);
        in.putExtra("strServQuan", strServQuan);
        in.putExtra("strMilkQuan", strMilkQuan);
        in.putExtra("strWaterQuan", strWaterQuan);
        in.putExtra("strDecocQuan", strDecocQuan);
        in.putExtra("strPowderQuan", strPowderQuan);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, in);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        backWithData();
        finish();
    }
```

And again in the previous activity I'm getting all values by overriding `onActivityResult`.

Here I'm trying to update the single item of ListView which was clicked to feed all values.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                pdtSupId = data.getStringExtra("pdtSupId");
                strKey = data.getStringExtra("strKey");
                strServQuan = data.getStringExtra("strServQuan");
                strMilkQuan = data.getStringExtra("strMilkQuan");
                strWaterQuan = data.getStringExtra("strWaterQuan");
                strDecocQuan = data.getStringExtra("strDecocQuan");
                strPowderQuan = data.getStringExtra("strPowderQuan");
                int first = listProductSup.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                int last = listProductSup.getLastVisiblePosition();
                for (int i=0; i<=pdtDataList.size(); i++)
                    if (pdtSupIdArr.get(i).equals(pdtSupId))
                        if (i == listItemPos) {
                            View view = listProductSup.getChildAt(i);
                            listProductSup.getAdapter().getView(i, view, listProductSup);
                            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.key_set)).setText(strKey);
                            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.serve_quan_set)).setText(strServQuan);
                            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.milk_quan_set)).setText(strMilkQuan);
                            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.wat_quan_set)).setText(strWaterQuan);
                            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.decoc_quan_set)).setText(strDecocQuan);
                            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.pow_quan_set)).setText(strPowderQuan);
                            break;
                        }
                 pdtAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

But I don't know why it is not getting updated.

To update the single item of `ListView` I got reference of other answers of `SO`. Like [Answer 1](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjz8PKl2djWAhXMrY8KHZtUBkgQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F2123083%2Fandroid-listview-refresh-single-row&usg=AOvVaw1LwafcxurrMZfNvg2jpUcT) and other answers too.

Comment: you should update underlaying data(pdtDataList) not the text in view

Comment: @Selvin can you please brief me, how can I update the data of single item here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, before `onBackPressed` change the data in the respective object and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Or, you could have a method like this (example from my project)

```
private void updateEventInList(boolean likeState, boolean followedState, int comments, int viewsNr, ViewHolder views) {
    if (parentFragment != null && parentFragment instanceof EventListFragment) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Position in list : " + positionInList + "\nlike / follow states : " + likeState + "/" + followedState + "\ncomments number : " + comments + "\nviews number : " + viewsNr);
        ((EventListFragment) parentFragment).updateList(positionInList, likeState, followedState, comments, viewsNr);
    }
}
```

Where `updateList` is something like this:

```
public void updateList(int positionInList, boolean likeState, boolean followedState, int numberOfComments, int numberOfViews) {
    eventsResponses.get(positionInList).setLiked(likeState);
    eventsResponses.get(positionInList).setFollowed(followedState);
    eventsResponses.get(positionInList).setComments(numberOfComments);
    eventsResponses.get(positionInList).setViews(numberOfViews);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Util.hideKeyboard(activity);
}
```

*Notice* that I called `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` . That is the listview's adapter. Hope this will help you

Comment: I'm using 2 activities here. `onBackPressed` method is in the 2nd activity and on the back pressed all data will be sent to the previous activity. My ListView should be updated with returned data from the 2nd, in the 1st activity.

Comment: Exactly as I was thinking :D `private void updateEventInList()` will be called in 2nd activity. If you take a look into that function it calls `public void updateList()` which is a public function in first activity (fragment in my case) So you just use your first activity instead of `parentFragment.updateList()`

Comment: Here `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called in `updateEventInList()` but my `adapter` and ListView is in the 1st activity.

Comment: No it is not called in `updateEventInList()` . the private function I show you above is in 2nd activity, and the public function is in first activity (which calls `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: I'm trying this idea, let me know, in your case it was updating a single row of listView like I've to do. pls be online I'll update you.

Comment: You can update one or more items in the list from within the 2nd activity / fragment. When something changes in your 2nd activity just call that method eachtime you make a change. Also take a look at the parameters, I have an `Integer positionInList` so I know which items has to be changed

Comment: But how you're getting `adapter` in 2nd activity if the `listView` is in the 1st.

Comment: If you refer to this line `((ViewPager)views.getViewPager(R.id.vp_images)).setAdapter(imageAdapter);` just ignore it .. It doesn't have to be there. Will edit the post now

Comment: Great bro!!! It's updated, but it's getting updated all items. But I need to update single one. I am getting item position, but how can I use this to update

Comment: Well, as I said you will have to replace variable `positionInList` with your variable. That parameter of the function tells it which item has to be changed

Comment: I am glad that I could help you, from here it will be a matter of context

Answer (score 1):

Hi Update the corresponding object in list onActivity result then call notifyDatasetChanged() , it will automatically update ui...

Comment: I'm calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` eventhen it's not getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your for loop

```
 for (int i=0; i<=pdtDataList.size()/.length; i++)
```

**UPDATE**

```
for (int i=0; i<=pdtDataList.length; i++)
                    if (pdtSupIdArr.get(i).equals(pdtSupId))
                        if (i == listItemPos) {
                            View view = listProductSup.getChildAt(i);
                            listProductSup.getAdapter().getView(i, view, listProductSup);
                            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.key_set)).setText(strKey);
                            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.serve_quan_set)).setText(strServQuan);
                            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.milk_quan_set)).setText(strMilkQuan);
                            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.wat_quan_set)).setText(strWaterQuan);
                            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.decoc_quan_set)).setText(strDecocQuan);
                            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.pow_quan_set)).setText(strPowderQuan);
                            break;
                        }
                 pdtAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

Comment: But here also I'm going from first item to last. It's equivalent, right?

Comment: no int first = listProductSup.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                int last = listProductSup.getLastVisiblePosition();   this gives you position of item which are visible you will not get complete size of your list

Comment: I've updated in my question. pls check in `onActivityResult` method.

Comment: I'm executing the same code, Here I've just updated. It's not getting updated.